# Is there a way to change monitor orientation using Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, multiple-monitors

Every time I turn my monitor I have to go in the settings, any way to automate the changing of the screen orientation in Python? I'm on Windows 10.

I have tried using the shortcut (ctrl alt right) but that doesn't work.

This is something ChatGPT came up with:

```
from screeninfo import get_monitors
import subprocess

def rotate_screen():
    # Get information about all monitors
    monitors = list(get_monitors())

    # Assuming the second monitor is the one you want to rotate
    if len(monitors) > 1:
        subprocess.run(["DisplaySwitch.exe", "/rotate:90"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rotate_screen()
```

displayswitch is for selecting how to mirror your screen to a second screen

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Display64.exe](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Screensavers/Noel-Danjou-Display.shtml) then the following code can be used.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['C:\\Users\\User\\Display64.exe','/device:2','/rotate:90','/toggle'])
```

more info can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/fuq7kx/program_to_rotate_and_position_2nd_monitor_help/) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/447155/how-do-i-set-up-a-hotkey-or-shortcut-to-rotate-my-screen-in-windows)